# How to add an image on ggplot background (not the panel)?

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, background

How do I use an image as the background for a ggplot2 plot?

For example, the code:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"))
```

It results in the following:
[image: plot]
and the background color is black.

How can I choose an image to be the background, and not only choose its color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can plot one on top of the other,

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill=NA))

library(grid)
grid.draw(gList(rasterGrob(img, width = unit(1,"npc"), height = unit(1,"npc")), 
                ggplotGrob(p)))
```

Answer (score 13):

We can use `ggpubr::background_image`. Here is a reproducible minimal example

```
library(ggpubr)
library(jpeg)

# Download and read sample image (readJPEG doesn't work with urls)
url <- "http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/rabbduck.jpg"
download.file(url, destfile = "rabbduck.jpg")
img <- readJPEG("rabbduck.jpg")

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
    background_image(img) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Species))
```

[image]

---

To use the whole canvas as plotting area for the background image, you can use `ggimage::ggbackground` (thanks @Marius)

```
library(ggimage)
g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Species))
ggbackground(g, url)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it only plots the image inside the panel. My doubt is, how to plot it outside the panel, as in the plot.background argument of the theme function? The image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWn0r.png) exemplifies the area I mean.

Comment: It looks like `ggimage::ggbackground()` does this https://guangchuangyu.github.io/2018/04/setting-ggplot2-background-with-ggbackground/, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: @Bruno Indeed, Marius is correct (many thanks!); I've made an edit to show an example.

Comment: @Marius Thanks, I think that's exactly what OP is after. It even works with URLs directly. I've made an edit.

Comment: Thanks, it already helps a lot!! But still, now the image overlaps the plotting area background, leaving the data a bit hard to see and interpret. Do you know some way to use the image as the "whole canvas" background, but still allowing the panel background to be different (for example, the light grey in the image I used in the question)

Comment: @Bruno Hmm. No I'm afraid I don't know. I had hoped you could simply add something like `theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))` to the `ggbackground` return object but that doesn't seem to work. The only option I see is to look into the individual grobs (you can use `ggplotGrob` to generate the plot grob), and manually change the panel on that level. This is a bit hacky/fiddly but shouldn't be too difficult. Unfortunately I don't have time to muck around with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a similar issue than OP - in regard to the background image being to intense and making the data less readable. I added a annotate("rect") with alpha parameter to tone down the background image.

```
library(ggpubr) 
image <- png::readPNG("image.png")   
df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
background_image(image) +
annotate("rect", 
          xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
          fill = "white", alpha = .5) + 
...
```