# Make a ggplot 0,0 XY coordinate to coincide with a specific point of a background image

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to combine two relevant things:

- A `ggplot` plot.
- And a background image.

There are several questions in this forum on how to implement [a background image in a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255832/how-to-add-an-image-on-ggplot-background-not-the-panel).

However, I would like to do so by taking into consideration a particular point of the background image. **I would like a specific point in the background image to be the XY coordinate (0,0) of the ggplot**.

## Data

Let's start with some data to illustrate what I want. Let's load `iris` dataset.

```
data(iris)
```

### We create the `ggplot()`

Now, let's create this scatterplot with the petal measurements.

```
g <- ggplot(iris, aes(x= Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() +
  xlim(0,7) + ylim(0,2.5) +
  theme_minimal()
print(g)
```

[image]

### Background image

This is the background image I would like to implement.

[image]

### Selecting the XY (0,0) coordinate in the image

This is the point of the background image where I would like to anchor the XY (0,0) of the ggplot.

[image]

## Expected output

The expected output must be anchoring the XY 0,0 of the `ggplot` to the selected point of the background image, no matter the size of the image.

It would be something like this:

[image]

How can I do it?