Accurately plotting on top of an image in R - dealing with plot areas, panels, origins and varying dimensions
I am trying to use R to insert text and charts over a background image.
There may be a better way of doing this, but some research has suggested that this is the best way (though it has some issues as detailed below)
I am using magick to read in the image, and then using cowplot::ggdraw() to draw in the data.
In order to get things easily aligned, I wish to be able to overlay a grid on top of the image, with the same origin as the image - however, different commands/packages appear to use different origins (e.g. starting with 0,0 as the axis intersection or the whole plot area). See provided images as to non-alignment of red grid origin with black grid origin.
Another problem, is that I need to be able to visually set up the labels (mainly by trial and error) and am using RStudio - but the plot window in RStudio is very dynamic regarding sizing and I would like to try and fix the size of the output.  Whilst theme(aspect.ratio=1) seems to sort out the worst problems with this, the accuracy of the point-grid relationship is still very dependent on the window size (see example pictures for relation of blue dots to background grids (black grid = image red grid = alignment grid). Consequently I need someway to fix the size of the displayed plot in the same way that you can fix the size of the image sent to file using ggsave (N.B. I am setting up the code plotting the text on manually - but the code will eventually be run automatically).
I realise that I may just be going about this in completely the wrong way so radical alternative methodologies rather than tinkering also welcome. However, the key points I am trying to resolve are:

How can I reliably fix a grid over an image so that the coordinates of the image features remain constant irrespective of the image/plot size?

How can I get the plot origin to line up with the bottom lefthand corner of the loaded/plotted image?


Simple reproducible demonstration code provided below - but ultimately we are trying to place text on to a background image to make an info graphic like this:



    if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
    pacman::p_load(data.table,magick, tidyverse,cowplot,ggpubr)

#Load Graphic
    pb<-image_read("https://art.pixilart.com/8c9cffeb529b204.png")
    
    #Choose this sets up the grid
    plotaxes<-ggplot()+ geom_point() + cowplot:: theme_nothing()+# ggpubr::theme_transparent()+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',colour = "red"),
            panel.grid.minor = element_line(linewidth = 0.1, linetype = 'solid',colour = "pink"))+ 
      scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),breaks=seq(1, 100, 10), minor_breaks = seq(1, 100, 1),limits=c(0,100))+
      scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),breaks=seq(1, 100, 10),minor_breaks = seq(1, 100, 1),limits=c(0,100))+theme(aspect.ratio=1)
    
    
    points<-data.table(x=seq(1,10),y=seq(1,10))
    plotpoints<-ggplot(points)+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y),colour="blue")+ggpubr::theme_transparent()
    
    ggdraw()+draw_image(pb)+draw_plot(plotaxes)+draw_plot(plotpoints)

   

On top of the image, I am then adding the text labels using cowplot:draw_label
The plotting of these dots definitely gets affected by the plot drawing (see next two pictures) - what better alternatives are there for placing text on the plot so it lines up with the grid no matter what dimensions the plot window is?
ggdraw()+draw_image(pb)+draw_plot(plotaxes)+draw_plot(plotpoints)+ draw_label(".This Point is at 0.2,0.2", x=0.2, y =0.2, color = "green", size = 15, angle = 0,hjust=0,vjust=0,fontfamily="HelveticaNeue",fontface="bold")+ draw_label(".This Point is at 0.5,0.5", x=0.5, y =0.5, color = "green", size = 15, angle = 0,hjust=0,vjust=0,fontfamily="HelveticaNeue",fontface="bold")+ draw_label(".This Point is at 0.8,0.8", x=0.8, y =0.8, color = "green", size = 15, angle = 0,hjust=0,vjust=0,fontfamily="HelveticaNeue",fontface="bold")


Just for reference...in case I don't get a response to this by tomorrow morning, my next steps are to start taking measurements of the (non-square in my real-life case) base image and fitting a grid to it more tightly and to the right proportions, and then exploring using annotate to redo the text.

OK - exploring some further alternatives (which fail) here are some further points I am trying to achieve:

Ideally I want to load the image and then plot over it so that the image can stay the same aspect ratio and the grid can be  fixed to it e.g. this method using ggpubr::background_image.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255832/how-to-add-an-image-on-ggplot-background-not-the-panel
I can't use readPNG as the image quality seems to end up being inadequate - so I seem fairly committed to magick



I really want to fix the bottom left corner of the image to the axis origins ggdraw()+draw_image()+draw_plot() doesn't appear to do this


Just to be clear about why the coordinate shift with gravity is a pain, is that I don't want to centre locate all my annotations - and so having to change coordinate systems for each label is really sub-optimal!

I had the same difficulty trying to produce a periodic table.  My solution, was to produce the table, as a graphical object, and then add labels and lines.
It depends on the background image.  If its a simple grid, then this may work for you.
For example:
# Data for grid, points and labels
box_data <- tibble(x = rep(1:10, each = 10), y = rep(1:10, length.out = 100))
line_data <- tibble(x = seq(1:9)*1.02+0.5, y = seq(1:9)*1.02+0.5)
label_data <- tibble(x = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8), y = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8), label = NULL)
    
offset <- 0.45 # Change the size of boxes

# Draw image
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = box_data, aes(xmin = x-offset, xmax = x+offset, ymin = y-offset, ymax = y+offset), fill = "white", colour = "grey60", linewidth = 2) +
  
  geom_hline(data = line_data, aes(yintercept = y), colour = "darkred") +
  geom_vline(data = line_data, aes(xintercept = y), colour = "darkred") +
  
  geom_text(data = label_data, aes(x = x*10, y = y*10, label = glue::glue("This point is at {x*10}, {y*10}")), hjust = -0.1,
            color = "darkgreen", size = 5, fontface="bold") +
  
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "red", size = 4) +
  
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  
  coord_equal() +
  
  theme_void()



Thanks.... the issue though is that the background images are like the ones n the post (with the green and black petrol pumps)

In my example I am providing two grids (one loaded as an image and one plotted) because:
a) In the real case I want to temporarily plot a grid over my image so that I can work out the coordinates for the text easily
b) by using a grid as the image in this example, I can show the issues of things not lining up well (especially getting the origins aligned.
So essentially the problems are about the alignment of the plot area with the image and the coordinate system for the annotation - so might try your use of geom_text and see how that goes
